# Sequelize: Force update for a JSON array

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Sequelize won't update a JSON field under some circumstances.

For example, I have:

```
[[1]] (an array inside array)
```

And I'm trying to push something:

```
instance.arr[0].push(1); // [[1,1]]
instance.save();
// or:
instance.update({arr: instance.arr});
```

Now inside the instance I have changed the array and nothing changed inside the database. Not even a query is sent. :(

From the Sequelize website:

> https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-instances.html
> The save method is optimized internally to only update fields that really
> changed. This means that if you don't change anything and call save,
> Sequelize will know that the save is superfluous and do nothing, i.e.,
> no query will be generated (it will still return a Promise, but it
> will resolve immediately).

That's good, but it seems like it doesn't work for JSON. Can I do a force update?

As of today, I have to do a deep copy of the array to save it.

I'm using [MariaDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MariaDB). I don't know if that matters.

Comment: If you just make a shallow copy so that the array reference itself changes, i.e. `instance.arr = [...instance.arr]` before pushing, does it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you have to specify that the field has changed

```
instance.changed( 'arr', true);
instance.save
```